# Load multiple scripts from a shared folder in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to share a global repository with a few python scripts that could be called from the pipeline Jenkinsfile.

I created the global share and added the `@Library('...') _` to the Jenkinsfile. It clones the repo specified but I do not know how to call the scripts from that shared pipeline folder or do I have to put the scripts in a resource/ folder?

I haven't been able to find any specifics for this. Some of the scripts in that repo depend on each other. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your Jenkinsfile - load the script with libraryResource

```
 script = libraryResource 'my_script.py'
```

and use it

```
sh script
```

Comment: I've seen that example before and the Jenkins documentation but it is not clear how to load, for example, two python scripts `a.py` and `b.py` from the resources folder then execute `a.py`.

Comment: This is what I did now but does not seem to be the most optimal. 
_resources\testFile.groovy_
``` def Test() {
final pythonContent = libraryResource('a.py')
final pythonContent1 = libraryResource('b.py')
writeFile(file: 'a.py', text: pythonContent)
writeFile(file: 'b.py', text: pythonContent1)
sh('python a.py')
}```
then I call in Jenkinsfile using `script { testFile.Test() }`
I'd rather not write to the target's workspace. I just want the output text file generated by `a.py` to be copied to the target's workspace.
Is there a better way to do this so it can be used globally.

Comment: I don't think shared library is correct solution for you. Better way is to just clone both repo in workspace and run a.py

Comment: The /resources folder should allow me to have non-groovy scripts. Cloning a new repo in Jenkinsfile would be cumbersome in my opinion. I don’t want to tell each project owners to clone a specific repo for that. I’d rather tell them to add the @Library and call the function to output the required text file.

Comment: I guess a good solution might be to do all the processing inside a temp location in workspace and then cleanUp after generating the output. That way there is less chance of clients workspace getting corrupted